# How to PUSH data between a Local DB Server to Cloud DB Server?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I have an implementation doubt regarding replicating data between SQL Server 2014 database servers (Replicating data from Local Premises SQL Server to Cloud DB Server, which are not in same domain or VPN).

May I request you to please advise a solution, to achieve this data transfer push from Local DB Server to Cloud DB Server.

I will elaborate the scenario over here, what we are trying to achieve.

***SCENARIO***

My client has an ETL application developed in .NET which uses SQL Server as a backend.

They have their Live SQL Server hosted on a cloud provider (not Microsoft Azure)

They are opening up a new branch which does not have a leased line, since the area is on outskirts of the city. This new branch will have almost 1500 users who will make entries to a locally hosted application which will use local DB Server.

They have 2 SQL Servers:

1. SQL Server 2014 Web Edition Database on Cloud (not Azure)
2. SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition with same Application database on Local Premises

They need to push the data entries inserted in local DB Server Database named as LabProdData to the Cloud DB Server Database LabProdData, so all other branches can refer to this branch data, with a certain delay of 30 minutes or less.

What are the options to implement this scenario?

**SOLUTION PROPOSED**

I have proposed a solution of ETL creation to open up a SQL Port on the Cloud DB server to facilitate communication to Local DB Server and to push data to the Cloud DB Server
But, this will be quite hectic to develop multiple ETL's since the number of tables are more.
Also, the Deletion and Updation of Data needs to be tracked and Synced, which will add up complexity

My client is bit hesitant about opening the port on Cloud DB Server, since this can be vulnerable to threats.

**REQUEST SOLUTION**

My doubts are:

1. Can we use SQL Server Replication to replicate the data between Local SQL Server and Cloud DB Server, with no Active Directory or no common domain?
2. If yes, how do we implement this scenario using SQL Server Replication?
3. Is there any other way to implement this scenario, other than Replication? Can you please suggest.
4. Can Replication or Database Mirroring help here
5. Can SQL Server Replication support this with 2 DB Servers of same version but one is Web Edition and other is Standard. We need to push data from Standard Edition to Web Edition.
6. How can the communication be implemented between both these servers? Note: Network Domain or Active Directory do not exists.

Please do let me know if you need any further details to understand the problem statement.
Eagerly awaiting for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question but may come in handy for others facing similar dilemma.

Your client is correct. Do no open up ports to the world, as this is will create a security risk. You will want a site-to-site VPN between your back offices and "the cloud". Once this is implemented the "the cloud" SQL will be accessible as if it was in your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you the trick.
Create your own ssh/serversocket server which will not expose your computer especially cmd or therminal.

create another client connection which will open port for local and clould communiction(ssh client).
I was able to do that using java.
I authenticate login using mysql server on clould and restricted the IP

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing more details

Answer (score 0):

for communication between local machine to cloud mysql works well but for cloud connection to mysql is not possible.
unless you use port forwarding or ssh tunnelling.
for trial you can use putty to open remote port on your through tunnelling.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194326)